# How to rearrange a list of lines in all possible ways and write those to files via bash script?

Tags: bash, sorting, csv, combinations, lines

I did some measurements and got a list of 132 lines in a csv file. The data looks like this:

```
    13,5;26;10;45,2;48,3
    13,5;26;15;49,7;52,9
    13,5;26;20;54,8;58,0
```

I would like to write all possible combinations of those lines into files, from outputs of a single line to a maximum of 44 lines. The order in which they mentioned in the files does not matter.

I would appreciate any hints and/or help.

kind regards,
Markus

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want to do this?

The number of all possible combinations of 44 lines out of 132 is the binomial coefficient "132 over 44", in Mathematica `Binomial[132,44]`. The result is:

226796193797561323702851561158682000

and then we did not even consider the 43 lines out of 132, the 42 lines out of 132, ... . That's a hell of a lot of files :-)

Comment: You are right, that are way too many combinations, I will need to tweak my filtering first. How would I write a script for fewer combinations?

Comment: Here is an example: 4 lines in the input file {a,b,c,d}, each letter stands for a line. You want 2 lines in the output files. Total number of output files is 6: {a,b}, {a,c}, {a,d}, {b,c}, {b,d}, {c,d}. Can be implemented as nested for loops. You will need as many nested for loops as the number of lines you want to have in the output files. `bash` is terribly inadequate for this kind of stuff though. And... how shall I say... I cannot really see the point of this exercise anyway. Let me ask again: are you sure you want to do this? :-)